# Android CORS Bug?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cors

I have a web page, created with jQuery + jQM that makes a cross domain call to register users.  This works perfectly - on all Desktop browsers, iPads and iPhones.  However, on Android something unusual appears to be happening.  Looking at my server logs I can see that the request was made and that the appropriate reply was issued.  But then... the reply just vanishes into the ether.  I have error handlers in my client side code just in case but they throw up nothing.  It is as though the server never replied at all.

I have tried this on my own, ancient, Xperia Ray (Android 2.3.5) and on a handful of phones on Browser stack - e.g. Motorola Razr (Android 4.1).  Always the same result. Debugging JavaScript on phones, viewing console output etc is no easy matter so I find myself at a loss to understand just what is going on here.

I'd much appreciate any tips from anyone who might have encountered similar issues - or failing that techniques I might be able to use to pin down the problem.  Googling for Android + CORS etc has produced nothing terribly useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer here for anyone who is trying to track down similar issues.  The problem in this particular instance was being caused by the fact that the user registration request was being made to one server (A) which in turn relayed it to another one (B) and then sent back the results.  A was marking the results it returned with the text/plain, ascii content type header.  However, B was returning text/plain utf-8.  This resulted in the string being returned to JavaScript starting with a BOM marker.

Android is unique amongst browsers in that it is unable to parse strings with a BOM marker to integers, floats or JSON.  In my instance I was attempting a parseInt that yielded a NaN on Android.  I was testing the int parsed results in a CASE statement with no DEFAULT clause so the NaN slipped through silently - no errors, no nothing.  Like the request vanished.

The moral of the tale - stick in a default handler in CASE statements, even when you are "sure" that you don't need it.

On a more practical note, if you want to echo back results picked up from another server do an [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) on the results prior to sending them out.  For example

```
iconv('utf-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE',$result);
```